# Catagorical variables with very uneven distributions? Removal/modify/leave?

Tags: categorical-data, nonlinear-regression, regression-strategies

In my current dataset I have quite a few categorical variables.
Most have decent distributions between the categories. 30:40:30 splits etc. where these are percentage of dataset members per category

dataset is ~2000 members

But a fair few have either (I feel) useless or difficult distributions.

Some have distributions like 97:2:1  - to me there are so few members in the low populated categories I would just leave this variable out. There may only be 10-20 members in the 1% category.

Others have distributions where I am not sure what to do. 
80:10:5:5 etc 
if it makes real world sense, with this option is combining the 10:5:5 portion into one group viable? Ie the new variable has 2 categories comprising 80:20 split in members.

With decision trees I do not think this is too much of a problem as it will effectively do the combining itself. 
With other modelling methods where dummy variables are created is the combining (or even removal) of variables an encouraged method as it also helps reduce dimensionality?

Comment: It certainly can be advisable to remove such variables from models, or to combine categories, where it makes substantive sense. (Depends rather on your modelling goals, which you haven't mentioned.) It's important to remember that the variables in a data-set aren't God-given "predictors"- it's up to you to form a useful model from them with one eye on their meaning & the other on the limitations of the data.

Comment: Goals in this case are to explore what input variables affect a chosen output variable of interest. particularly ones not already known. Myself, i can guess, there are other people who know more. I find the advantage of myself not really knowing i am less biased but still having understanding. Im glad i am on the right track, my problem with this sort of stats is usually i am not sure if methods i have thought up are acceptable/valid. And yes, usually most predictors are irrelevant in the end (with this data)

Comment: A lot of applied statistics books start with the supposition that the model is just *known*, & deal with these sort of issues poorly if at all. I'd highly recommend the two mentioned [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106235/106303#106303).

Comment: I looked at the Steyerberg sample chapter. Thankfully no deep proof mathematical equations, im fairly good at maths until it gets very pure. The chapters seem fairly relevant to what i do (in general) so thank you. I feel i need to adjust my data as with for example neural nets my outliers do seem to have huge leverage on my validated models. Stepwise and decision trees handle this far far better. Can you explain what you mean by 'model is just known'

Comment: Having just looked at some of the descriptions of the earlier book i have to say the topics covered are all problems that i have to deal with. What looks particularly useful is strategy focus as opposed to theory. variable reduction, normality, colinearity etc are all issues for me

Comment: I meant that many books deal with model fitting, interpretation, & diagnostics; but not with how to come up with a model in the first place. Though not dealing with it is better than the rather half-assed section on "Model Selection" or the like that you sometimes see in otherwise very good books.

Comment: I think that is a problem for me. Its not the fitting of the model its processing or not the predictors. It the 'Do I?' question..do i take this out? do i compress this? what do i use to do this? What modelling method do i use given my data. If the bricks aren't right how can the built model be? Having more confidence here would be amazing

Comment: You have to use knowledge to define the bricks - why shouldn't the response be high for odd values of a predictor & low for even values? One handy tip from the book relevant to your question: you can use the coefficient of determination from a regression of the rank of the response on the dummy variables for a categorical predictor to measure how strongly that predictor relates to the response (marginally). Combining some categories for the ones that relate less strongly doesn't bias predictions much.

Comment: I am finding that literally 1 or 2 outliers in some cases can affect significance of the predictor. If its true that's fine but so few points = little confidence. but methods like ANNs cause problems here. With your tip, what do you mean by rank of response?